# Time complexity nested loops or not

Tags: time, case, complexity-theory

I’ve been assigned to analyze this pseudo code

I’ve tried to sketch the code out and I came to the conclusion that this code computes the sum of elements in an array A then decides whether it’s a prime number or not . Am I correct ?
Now I’m trying to figure out it’s worst case time complexity
So far I’ve concluded
Line 1,13 O(1)
Line 2-4 O(n)
Line 5-8 O(n)
Line 8-10 O(n-1)
Line 4,7,11,12 ——
Is it safe to say it’s worst case time complexity is O(n)?

```
Input: Array A with the length |A|=n `
of the natural numbers a in N ^ >=1 
Output: Boolean value 
1.  x:= 0;
2.  For i:= 1 to n do 
3.  x:= x + A[i];
4.  End for 
5.  If x<2 then 
6.  Return false; 
7.  End if 
8.  For i:= 2 to x -1 do
9.  If x mod i=0 then 
10. Return false; 
11. End if 
12. End for 
13. Return true;
```